# Angular httpClient catchError doesn't return error object

Tags: angular-httpclient, rxjs6

I am trying to implement  a global error handling by creating an interceptor. here is its code:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpSentEvent
   HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any> | any> {
return next.handle(request)
  .pipe(
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        switch (error.status) {
          case 406: {
            return error406(request, next);
          }
      }} else {
        return throwError(error);
      }
    }));
```

The initial call is like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/web/wrongapi/`)
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

}

The console looks like this:
11:23:04.568 GET https://localhost/api/web/wrongapi/ 404

11:23:04.608 ERROR OK

When I check "error" it is a string = "Ok"

My question is:
Why I am not getting an error object in my catchError?

If my backend returns just a string how then Console knows it is 404?

Thanks